# How do I run my php script?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, tomcat

I'v installed Apache Tomcat and it's running. I have a php file which I want to run. Where do I have to put my php file so that going to `http://localhost:8080/myPage.php` (in my browser) will result in executing my php script?

EDIT: My OS is Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right.  I suspect you're quite confused here.

Apache Tomcat is a container for java applications.  I think you should have installed Apache Web Server, and PHP.  There's no sensible way to get Tomcat to handle PHP (without Resin, but that's a different story).

You'd probably be best to install XAMPP and use the server packages provided by that.

Comment: Thanks. If I install Apache Web Server (and PHP) will it coexist with my Apache Tomcat (which I also use)?

Comment: Yeah, should be fine.  Tomcat generally "lives" on port 8080, and Apache Webserver "lives" on port 80.  I frequently use both on the same server with no problem.  You could just ditch Tomcat if you never intend to deploy java web applications.

Answer (score 0):

Check out: http://webdevcodex.com/tutorial-installing-apache2-php5-mysql5-phpmyadmin3-windows-7-vista/